# GridView Paging not working with jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, paging

I am working with asp.net page that is being loaded by using jquery ajax. In this page I am using Gridview to display list of values as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVPrograms" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        onrowcommand="GVPrograms_RowCommand" AllowPaging="true" BackColor="#f5f5f5"  BorderColor="#ffffff"
         PageSize="2" OnPageIndexChanging="GVPrograms_PageEventHandler" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>             

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Video">
                    <ItemTemplate>                    

                     <div style="float: left; width: 120px" class="play-video"> 
                         <a href="Program.aspx?id=<%#Eval("ID") %>" id='<%#Eval("ID") %>'>                          
                         <img src='<%# GetUrl(Eval("ID")) %>' width='100' height='100' style="" alt="play" />

                         </a>

                       </div>
 </asp:TemplateField> 
 </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

I have handled the paging in the PageEventHandler method and is working fine. But whenever the page is first loaded and when I click any of the links inside the gridview, the Program.aspx page is loaded using the following script

```
$(".play-video a").click(function () {
              $("#content-placeholder").load(this.href);                
              //alert(this.id);
              return false;
          });
```

Now, the issue is whenever I click the next page(say page 2) and click any of the links, the Program.aspx is rather getting displayed in a new window. So, how can I make this to still get loaded in the same page by using the above jquery script?

I have been searching if there are any workarounds for this but couldn't find any. I appreciate your help.

Comment: do you have place your gridview inside update panel ?

Comment: @Aristos, yes I have put it inside Update panel. Sorry forgot to include it here though.

Comment: If you are using update panel, you will need to register client script using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock every time the panel is rendering again.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `UpdatePanel` you need to re-initialize your javascript that work with the content of this `UpdatePanel` on every update and this is because you change the Dom struct and the previous javascript is not working any more.

To do that you use the functions that UpdatePanel provide and your code will be as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // this is your function that we must call on page load 
    //  and after updatepanel updates.
    function InitMyLink()
    {
      $(".play-video a").click(function () {
        $("#content-placeholder").load(this.href);                
        return false;
      });
    }

    // now I capture the two functions that called when UpdatePanel is updated
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
    }

    // this is called after update panel completes the update
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        InitMyLink();
    }

    // this is called on first page load
    $(document).ready(function() {
      InitMyLink();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working. Even during the first page load, when i click the link it is taking me to a new page.

Comment: @semytech see f you get any javascript error. This code is working for sure... :)

Comment: I don't have any javascript except this one in the page and I don't know why it is not working with me. By the way, your code seems very reasonable and will try to figure it out why it is failing to work.

Comment: @semytech place an alert inside the InitMyLink() see if called, then the issue will be the sellections. Maybe the `content-placeholder` not found.

Comment: I think the problem is, the `$(document).ready(function() {
      InitMyLink();
    });` is not getting rendered. I tried to display an alert message inside and nothing is happening.

Comment: @semytech then remove the ready(), just make the call to `InitMyLink();`